# Autofac constructor injection on an Attribute

Tags: .net, attributes, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have an Attribute where I'm attempting to use Autofact and Dependency Injection.
The attribute resides in a .Net assembly, not MVC.

ex

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute{
   IMyDependentClass _myDependentClass;
   public MyAttribute (IMyDependentClass  myDependentClass){
         // This fails because attributes can't have a
         // constructor with parameters
         _myDependentClass = myDependentClass;
   }
   private void MyAttributeEvent(object Sender, MyEventArgs e){
          e.Result = _myDependentClass.MyMethod(e.Expression);
   }
}
```

Comment: Attributes are meta-**data** emphasis on the data so you should not put complex logic in attributes. Instead move your logic form your attributes to your infrastructure code where you use your attributes. By the way attributes can have constructor parameters only the usable types are limited: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx so you cannot have interface typed parameters.

Comment: And don't forget that the only CLR creates attributes at runtime. You can't delegate the creation to your container.

Comment: i was afraid of that, I'm trying to subclass a 3rd party's templating engine, and their custom macros are implemented by inheriting an attribute class

Comment: You can use property injection on attributes instead of constructor injection.